# DKIM amavisd test failed

Tags: email, centos, email-validation, dkim

I have configured a new email server for my company, we are using a cloud server on theplanet.com and a shared hosnting on bluehost.com, I configured the server using iredmail, all works great but when I try to test the dkim keys with amavisd testkeys it returns:

```
TESTING#1: dkim._domainkey.mydomain.com   => invalid (public key: not available)
```

I set the dns record on dns panel in blehost

```
name: mail._domainkey
type: txt  
value:"v=DKIM1; p=MIGfM......"
```

when I try to validate via `auth@verifier.port25.com` it returns

```
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         permerror (key "dkim._domainkey.mydomain.com" doesn't exist)
```

Please help me with this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a DNS record of `mail._domainkey.mydomain.com` but your DKIM signer is using a selector of `dkim` therefore it's looking up `dkim._domainkey.mydomain.com`.  If you rename the DNS record so that they match up it should work.